# How to separate these bits into blocks of 8 bits in Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

In my program, you will see something like this:
000000000000001000000010000000010
But I would like something like this instead(easier to read):
00000000 00000100 000001000 00000100

(It's just an exemple)

How do I do this? I believe I need to change something in my PUT_BIN procedure but I don't know what.
Here's my code:

```
       PAGE    80,132
;===================================================================
;                   PROGRAM LISTING 5.1
;
;PROGRAM TO DEMONSTRATE SUBROUTINE INTERFACE
;
;===================================================================
       .MODEL  SMALL,BASIC,FARSTACK
;===================================================================
                                   ;PROCEDURES TO
       EXTRN   NEWLINE:FAR         ;DISPLAY NEWLINE CHARACTER
       EXTRN   PUTDEC:FAR          ;DISPLAY DECIMAL INTEGER
;===================================================================
; S T A C K   D E F I N I T I O N
;
       .STACK  256

SHL32   MACRO   REG1, REG2
    SHL     REG2, 1
    RCL     REG1, 1
    ENDM

SHR32   MACRO   REG1, REG2
    SHR     REG1, 1
    RCR     REG2, 1
    ENDM
;===================================================================
; C O D E   S E G M E N T   D E F I N I T I O N
;
       .CODE
;
 EX_5_1:
       MOV     BL,1               
       MOV     DI,0001H            
       MOV     SI,0010H
       MOV     DL,1 

       MOV      AX, DI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         
       MOV      AX, SI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         
       CALL     NEWLINE      


       SHL32   DI,SI

        MOV     AX, DI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         
       MOV      AX, SI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         
       CALL     NEWLINE                

                                   ;
                                   ;

        SHR32    DI,SI ;

       MOV      AX, DI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         
       MOV      AX, SI
       CALL     PUT_BIN         
       CALL     NEWLINE         

       CALL    NEWLINE             ;SKIP TO NEXT LINE ON DISPLAY
       .EXIT                       ;RETURN TO DOS
;
       PAGE
;===================================================================
; PROCEDURE TO DISPLAY AN 8- OR 16-BIT VALUE IN BINARY FORM
;
; INPUT:  AL-REG  8-BIT  VALUE TO BE DISPLAYED
;         BL=0    CODE FOR  8-BIT DISPLAY
;               OR
;         AX-REG  16-BIT VALUE TO BE DISPLAYED
;         BL<>0   CODE FOR 16-BIT DISPLAY
;
; OUTPUT: INPUT VALUE DISPLAYED IN BINARY FORM ON THE
;         SCREEN BEGINNING AT CURRENT CURSOR POSITION
;===================================================================
PUT_BIN    PROC    NEAR             ;PROCEDURE PUTBIN(NUMBER,CODE)
       PUSH    AX                  ;SAVE REGISTERS
       PUSH    DX
       PUSH    DI
       PUSH    BX
       PUSH    CX
       PUSHF                       ;SAVE FLAGS
       CMP     BL,0                ;IF   CODE = BYTE (BL=0)
       JNZ     _ELSE
       MOV     AH,0                ;THEN EXPAND NUMBER TO 16 BITS
       MOV     CX,8                ;     BIT_COUNT = 8
       JMP     _ENDIF
_ELSE:                                 ;ELSE
       MOV     CX,16               ;     BIT_COUNT = 16
_ENDIF:                                ;ENDIF
       MOV     BX,2
       MOV     DI,CX               ;SAVE BIT_COUNT
LOOPTOP:                               ;REPEAT
       MOV     DX,0                ;   BIT = NUMBER mod 2
       DIV     BX                  ;   NUMBER = NUMBER / 2
       PUSH    DX                  ;   PUSH BIT
       LOOP    LOOPTOP             ;   DECREMENT BIT_COUNT
                                   ;UNTIL BIT_COUNT = 0
       MOV     CX,DI               ;RESTORE BIT_COUNT
       MOV     BH,0                ;<DISPLAY CODE>
_REPEAT:                               ;REPEAT
       POP     AX                  ;   POP BIT
       CALL    PUTDEC              ;   DISPLAY BIT
       LOOP    _REPEAT             ;   DECREMENT BIT_COUNT
                                   ;UNTIL BIT_COUNT = 0
       POPF                        ;RESTORE FLAGS
       POP     CX                  ;RESTORE REGISTERS
       POP     BX
       POP     DI
       POP     DX
       POP     AX
       RET                         ;RETURN
PUT_BIN    ENDP                     ;END PUTBIN
       END     EX_5_1
```

Comment: Why do people always use ancient assembly books? Must be some time when there were only captial letters ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
    ...
_REPEAT:
```

insert something like

```
    test    cx, 7       ;test if loop counter can be divided by eight
    jnz     nospace
    mov     al, 32      ;a space
    call    PUTCHAR
nospace:
```

after that the old program continues.

```
    POP     AX
    ...
```

I don't know if a PUTCHAR subroutine exists, nor what register it uses or clobberes. I just assumed it uses AL as input register and saves everything.